# Redux how to get updated store state in root component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

My root `App` component looks like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const state = store.getState();
    const { isAuthenticated } = state.auth;

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter basename="/">
          <Switch>
            {isAuthenticated ? (
              <PrivateRoute
                exact
                path="/library/:user_id"
                component={RessourcesByUser}
              />
            ) : (
              <PublicRoute
                exact
                path="/library/:user_id"
                component={PublicRessourcesByUserPage}
              />
            )}
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

---

The problem with `isAuthenticated` is that when the app is first loaded **before the user logs in** its value is `false`.

And it makes sense since the user **has not logged in yet**.

The problem is that **when he logs in**, the `App` component **does not mount again** (obviously), nor does it get the updated store state in which `isAuthenticated` is `true`.

So `isAuthenticated` here in `App` component will remain `false` even though the user **is authenticated** and its value **in the store** is `true`.

It will change to `true` here once he refreshes because `App` component will get the updated state then in which `isAuthenticated` is `true`.

However, meanwhile this will cause **logical bugs** such as when he goes to a user's `Library` right after **loading the app and logging-in the first time** by clicking on a button that would direct to this path `/library/:user_id`, he will see the public component `PublicRessourcesByUserPage` that is meant to be displayed for **non-authenticated users** instead of `RessourcesByUser` which is meant for **authenticated users**.

Comment: You should subscribe to the store. You could use [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) in your case (class component) or [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) is case of hooks.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used react-router, but if you want to get the freshest (reactive) state with Redux, then your component will need to be *connected* to Redux. So something along these lines:

```
import  { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AuthRoutes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        {this.props.isAuthenticated ? (
          <PrivateRoute
            exact
            path="/library/:user_id"
            component={RessourcesByUser}
          />
        ) : (
          <PublicRoute
            exact
            path="/library/:user_id"
            component={PublicRessourcesByUserPage}
          />
        )}
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}

connect((state) => ({ isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated }),null)(AuthRoutes);

---

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter basename="/">
          <AuthRoutes />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Note: I'm making an assumption that `Switch` will work OK like this.